# Is the Restriction of a Borel Function Itself Borel?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The question in the title, which I suspect is wrong, comes from this problem:

Let $\{f_n\}_{n\in N}$ be a sequence of Borel functions $f_i : R^d \to [-\infty, \infty]$. Suppose $\{E_n\}_{n \in N}$ is a sequence of Borel sets in $R^d$, which form a pair-wise disjoint cover of $R^d$.

define $f(x) = f_n(x)$ if $x \in E_n$, and show that $f$ is Borel.

I tried multiple ways around this, and almost every path lead me to the point I had to prove that $\{u \in E_i | f_i(u) \in A\}$, for $A$ open, is itself Borel. That set is the pre-image of $A$ under $f_i$ restricted to $E_i$.
I don't know if this the path to take, but I haven't yet used, or seen the necessity of $E_i$ being Borel.

Comment: Are the $f_n$ Borel functions? If not, $f$ is rather unlikely to be a Borel function.

Comment: I would suspect that the $f_k$ are Borel and that $f$ is given by $f = f_n \cdot 1_{E_n}$?

Comment: @DanielFischer yes, edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, we have

$$\{u \in E_k : f_k(u) \in A\} = \bigl(f_k\lvert_{E_k}\bigr)^{-1}(A) = f_k^{-1}(A) \cap E_k.$$

If $A$ is open (or a Borel set, more generally), then $f_k^{-1}(A)$ is a Borel set by definition of a Borel function, and then $f_k^{-1}(A) \cap E_k$ is also a Borel set if $E_k$ is one.

Comment: yup, thanks Daniel